# How to create a fluent pagination for mobile devices on a responsive website

Tags: ios, css, mobile, web, uiscrollview

I want users of my website to use pagination on their mobile devices, like for example UIScrollView with paging enabled in iOS.
Still the website should also be viewable on desktops.

So far, I tried [Foundation's orbit](http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/components/orbit.html), but that just doesn't feel fluent at all (when you release your finger, it performs the sliding a little delayed).

Is there any good alternative on how to get this done? If possible I would like the user to even slide vertically as well as horizontally.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe [Swipe.js](https://github.com/thebird/Swipe) is the thing you looking for.

Comment: It is very responsive and fast with touch-screen devices and it's also very easy to use and manipulate :) You can try the demo with your mobile device here: http://thebird.github.io/Swipe/

Answer (score 2):

have you tried [SwipeView](http://cubiq.org/swipeview)?

[Here you have an demo gallery](http://cubiq.org/dropbox/SwipeView/demo/gallery/)

Answer (score 1):

I'm looking for this too, but I really think they are none.
If you want it to be fluid, you have create your own using CSS3 animation/transform and so it will not work on hold browser (IE < 10 or 11, but I'm not sure). If you want to handle touch events I recommend you to check out "jQuery Modile"

Answer (score 1):

You can try [iScroll 5](http://cubiq.org/iscroll-5) it's quite simple but do the trick perfectly.

You will find [in the archive of the project](https://github.com/cubiq/iscroll/archive/master.zip) an example of horizontal paging under `demos/carousel`, you will see it's quite good. :)

In addition you will be able to see all other things you can do with iScroll which should fit your demands.